# Vlans without assigning ip address

Tags: vlan

I have  a 6248 Dell switch with following vlan's created

```
interface vlan 2
name "ISCSI1"
exit
interface vlan 3
name "ISCSI2"
exit

interface vlan 4
name "CSV"
exit

interface vlan 5
name "LiveMigration"
exit

And have interfaces assigned to the vlan's.

interface ethernet 1/g2
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit


interface ethernet 1/g3
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit

interface ethernet 1/g4
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit


interface ethernet 1/g5
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit


interface ethernet 1/g6
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit


interface ethernet 1/g7
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 2
exit


interface ethernet 1/g8
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit


interface ethernet 1/g9
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit

interface ethernet 1/g10
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit

interface ethernet 1/g11
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit

interface ethernet 1/g12
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit


interface ethernet 1/g13
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 3
exit


interface ethernet 1/g14
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 4
exit


interface ethernet 1/g15
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 4
exit


interface ethernet 1/g16
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 4
exit

interface ethernet 1/g17
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 5
exit

interface ethernet 1/g18
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 5
exit


interface ethernet 1/g19
spanning-tree disable
spanning-tree portfast
mtu 9216
switchport access vlan 5
```

However there is not ip address assigned to vlan, No network is assigned to any vlan.

My question is are these vlan active and then how are they communicating with each other?

Answer (score 3):

VLANs exist at layer 2 in most networking models.  They do not communicate with anything automatically.  They don't do IP.  Since it has no IP we can also pretty assume your device is not configured as a layer 3 router.  If communication is happening, some other device on your network is facilitating it.  If there is no communication, and you are trying to add it, then you need to configure the routing functionality on some device that can see all the VLANs you need to communicate.

Comment: there is a sonicawall attached to switch through another switch however there is no inter vlan routing on sonic wall for these vlans.

Comment: what if all the  devices on different vlan ports are of same subnet, will inter vlan routing be needed then

Answer (score 1):

VLan interfaces declared with no ip address are here to act at layer 2 only.

However, you need to declare them to be able to setup `mode access` for specific vlan on physical interfaces.

In its actual config, your switch does not route any VLan.

For sure you have another router (may be a Firewall) with network defined so that your VLan can be routed. This router is the one that makes your VLans able to communicate each other.

Comment: There is a firewall attached however there are no vlan subinterface configured on it as well. –  X0 LAN   192.168.1.77 255.255.252.0 Static 1 Gbps Full Duplex Default LAN Edit this entry 
 X0:V60 LAN   10.0.80.4 255.255.240.0 Static VLAN Sub-Interface DEV/SUP Domain V... Edit this entry Delete this entry 
 X0:V90 LAN   10.0.128.3 255.255.240.0 Static VLAN Sub-Interface QA Domain VLAN Edit this entry Delete this entry